# python index out of bounds error

Tags: python, list, pandas

Tryind this code:

```
f2 = []
for i in symb_list: 
    f2.append(earnings_vola(i))
```

Gives the index out of bounds error. Sample of symb_list:

```
symb_list
Out[143]:
['MTMC',
 'ANCI',
 'TPLM',
 'BERK',
 'DGI',
 'QLTY',
 'GST',
 'AGEN',
 'NURO',
```

earnings_vola(i) returns float

UPD. Sorry, im new user here.

```
def earnings_vola (symbol):
    price_b = marketdata.ext.load_metotron('%s'%symbol)
    price = price_b.sort()
    d = pickle.load(open('/home/mad/Appr/data_%s.pickle'%(symbol), 'rb'))
    df = h.to_df(d)
    if df['timetype'][2]=='After Close':
        price['VOLA'] = (price.shift(-1)['C']-price['C'])/price['C']*100
    else:
        price['VOLA'] = (price['C']-price.shift(+1)['C'])/price['C']*100
    x1 = pa.Series(sorted(df['Date_p']))
    px = price.reindex(x1, method='ffill')
    avg_vola = np.mean(px['VOLA'])
    return avg_vola
```

UPD2

```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-144-f3de6042c223> in <module>()
>       1 f2 = []
>       2 for i in symb_list:
> ----> 3     f2.append(earnings_vola(i))
> 
> <ipython-input-123-96f164ec1ad9> in earnings_vola(symbol)
>       4     d = pickle.load(open('/home/mad/Appr/data_%s.pickle'%(symbol), 'rb'))
>       5     df = h.to_df(d)
> ----> 6     if df['timetype'][2]=='After Close':
>       7         price['VOLA'] = (price.shift(-1)['C']-price['C'])/price['C']*100
>       8     else:
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in
> __getitem__(self, key)
>     616     def __getitem__(self, key):
>     617         try:
> --> 618             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
>     619         except InvalidIndexError:
>     620             pass
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in
> get_value(self, series, key)
>     728 
>     729             try:
> --> 730                 return tslib.get_value_box(series, key)
>     731             except IndexError:
>     732                 raise
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tslib.so in
> pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:8534)()
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tslib.so in
> pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:8378)()
> 
> IndexError: index out of bounds
```

**UPD3
Example of result earnings_vola(symbol) function:

```
earnings_vola(symbol='MSFT')
0.080011249349832989**
```

I need to iterate list of symbols (example above) and get all results in list

Comment: What is `earnings_vola`?

Comment: It is `earnings_vola(i)` that throws the exception.. What is in that function, and what is the **full** traceback.

Comment: And note that Python throws `IndexError` for lists, not *index out of bounds*.. which makes me really curious about what `earning_vola()` might be..

Comment: please write your complete code here. what is `earing_vola` ?

Comment: Please provide the actual traceback as well as the actual code. Almost certainly the exception is from some code inside that `earnings_vola` function, or something else that function calls. The traceback will tell you (or at least tell us, if you don't understand it) exactly which line of which function it's happening in. Then, if you've shown us the relevant code, we can start to debug it.

Comment: earnings_vola(i) returns float

Comment: You need to post the actual code describing `earnings_vola`, not just what it outputs

Comment: All the downvoters should bear in mind that this is a new user, and he should be given some time to correct his Q before downvoting him.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This _could_ be Jython code that's causing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` from Java. Otherwise, the fact that he used the exact name of that Java exception, and attached the tag for that exception, seems like a bit of a coincidence.

Comment: @SteinarLima: Remember that people can change their votes if he edits his question. (And that _could_ be a good way to convince people to actually edit the question instead of trying to post new code into comments… although I'm not sure that often works as well as it should…) But if the OP never comes back, you wouldn't want this question to be +7 and show up on all kinds of searches and so on, would you?

Comment: @abarnert: could be, or the OP had the Java exception in mind when the Python exception was thrown.

Comment: @abarnert I agree to some extent, but I don't think (you would know better, I'm sure, please correct me if I'm wrong) that most downvoters __don't__ change their vote, no matter how much the OP improves his Q.

Comment: Q updated. i can't past full traceback nor in post or comment :/

Comment: And I don't think downvoting motivates new users, on the contrary I think some users would just say f**k it, I'll ask somewhere else (but this discussion should be taken on meta)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's index error in python. I've just missclicked when writing tags.

Comment: @BiggieGv0: Now we are getting somewhere. Can you include the full traceback as well please? That'll save us having to guess. It'll be hard enough to reproduce your problem without knowing what files you are using and what external modules you have imported.

Comment: What do you mean "i can't past full traceback nor in post or comment"? You just copy the traceback, paste it into your question, and click the "code" button to indent it. What part of that isn't working?

Comment: @abarnert tried to do but there was some message about too much code and so on. I copyed it in text format and updated Q

Comment: @BiggieGv0: You formatted it as a quote instead of as code, but I fixed that for you. Now this is a great question. But unfortunately, I think we still need more information. We have no idea what data is supposed to be in that `DataFrame`, or what's there instead. And we can't run your code, because this isn't a complete sample program, just a fragment. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for some tips on stripping down your code enough that you can paste a complete sample.

Comment: @BiggieGv0: Alternatively, if you can adequately describe what's in all of the relevant variables so that we can figure out what the DataFrame should be holding, and why it isn't, that would work too… but that would probably be a lot harder for you to do (as I'm guessing there's a _lot_ of information, much of it harder to express in English than in Python).

Comment: Why did you just undo my formatting edit, making your traceback impossible to read again?

Comment: @abarnert TY fo helping me, i think i need to rewrite Q in terms of samples of variables. In other case i will need to post many strings of custom libs :/

Comment: @abarnert i don't ! i think we edit message simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
if df['timetype'][2]=='After Close':
```

And it's complaining that `df['timetype']` is a sequence with only 0, 1, or 2 items, but you're asking for the third.

This could be a silly typo of the kind we all make, where you accidentally wrote `2` instead of `1`, or forgot that Python sequences use 0-based indices.

But if not, if you really were expecting `df['timetype']` to have 3 or more values and it doesn't, we need to know what values you expected it to have, and why, and what values it *actually* has.

You can get started on debugging this by just adding a line to your code and running again:

```
    df = h.to_df(d)
    print(df['timetype']) # NEW CODE
    if df['timetype'][2]=='After Close':
```

If the result isn't what you expected, try printing out `df` itself, or `d` or `h`, etc., until you find the first place where it goes wrong.

At some point, you'll find the first step that's returning a different value than you expected. You may still have no idea *why* it's returning a different value—but at that point, you've got a much easier question for StackOverflow to answer.

Comment: @DSM: But that would return a `KeyError`, not an `IndexError`, wouldn't it? You only get an `IndexError` when you have an implicit index, right? Or is there a way to get something like a sparse implicit index that _could_ raise an `IndexError` for indexing into a gap?

Comment: D'you know, you're right, that'd be a `KeyError`, so that theory's dead.  The traceback is a little hard to read-- is the error with the `price` line?

Comment: @DSM: It's the `df['timetype'][2]`. Now that the formatting is fixed, you can see the chain of calls it goes through. But I don't know exactly how `tslib.get_value_box` works, and I don't want to go digging into the source code without any understanding of what the OP expects `df['timetype']` to hold or what it actually holds, because I don't think it would be illuminating enough to be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
if df['timetype'][2]=='After Close':
    price['VOLA'] = (price.shift(-1)['C']-price['C'])/price['C']*100
```

to this code (explicit, correct and readable)

```
key = 'timetype'
value = df[key] if df and key in df else None
kw = value[2] if value and len(value) > 2 and value[2]=='After Close' else None
if kw:
    price['VOLA'] = (price.shift(-1)['C']-price['C'])/price['C']*100
```